# Leaflet: Fire "loading map" transistion

Tags: leaflet

I notice that when the map first initiates, you see see this:

[image: map]

But how do I fire that say during an event.  For example:

```
             map.on("moveend", function (e) {
                    map.showLoadingTransition();
                    //DO STUFF
                    map.stopLoadingTransition();
            }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `map.remove()` then reinit map again

Comment: The problem with that is, there is an AJAX call in the "Do Stuff" part of my example, waiting on a result, the map init won't have the data yet.